# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setSelectionRange' on 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('number') does not support selection

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

i am using bootstrap x-editable to edit contents inline. But when i put data-type="number" then it shows this error on click that element

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setSelectionRange' on 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('number') does not support selection

all other data-types like text, select2, select, textarea, url, tel etc work fine instead number. So anyone have any idea how to get this error resolve. js files i am using are

> //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js
>   //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.4.6/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js

my html code is

```
<div class="container">

  <h1>X-editable starter template</h1>

  <div>
    <span>Username:</span>
    <a href="#" id="username" data-type="number" data-placement="right" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>Status:</span>
    <a href="#" id="status"></a>
  </div>


</div>
```

and my js code is

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';     

//make username editable
$('#username').editable();
```

Comment: Add your html & js code

Comment: @Dhn i have added html code in question itself.

Comment: any idea about the issue